# How to reject tenant applicant because co-applicant was rejected?

Tags: rental-property, landlord, rent

I'm rejecting a tenant's application because of his credit report. I do know what that denial letter should look like.

I'm sending his co-applicant a rejection letter too but I'm not sure of the correct  legal language to include.

Anyone know?

Comment: Have you chosen another tenant? I would assume the less you say, the better. That goes for both people. "I regret to inform you that I will not be leasing my property to you at this time." Why do you feel you need to go beyond that?

Comment: Typically some reason is given so no discrimination claims are made. For the one by law I need to say it was because of his credit report.

Comment: Interesting. Is this in the US? Is that federal or state law?

Comment: It's US law: 15 USC 1681

Comment: Surely 15 USC 1681 would not apply here as you are not a "consumer reporting agency", as you are not selling this information.

Comment: Can't say I'm an expert at the text of the fair credit reporting act but check section 615: Requirements on users of consumer reports. Read about the requirements when taking adverse action based on the credit report.

Answer (score 4):

If the application is joint, you're only declining one application, and you're doing that for reason of credit history.

Send the applicants one letter (or each applicant a copy of the same letter) which accords to the law of your jurisdiction, to inform them of the decision and the reason.

If you don't have permission to share personal information between co-applicants, simply say application was declined because co-applicant's was.

Comment: I wound up doing something like that but since the co-applicants weren't married, I didn't share why one of them was declined. Thought that could be considered sharing personal information which I may not be able to do. I'll suggest am update to your answer.

Comment: @joecap5 that's a good suggestion, I've approved now.